# GET request not in json content type flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to get data of a sqlite database in json format on a route on the website, this works as expected and if I'm going to that link it says in the networks tab in chrome devtools that de content type is application/json. This is ofcourse what I want, Except if I make a XML GET request with javascript to this specific route it says data type: text/html. Does anyone know how to fix this? The python flask code:

```
@app.route('/dossiers/all', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def get_all_dosssiers():
    ids = executeQueryResult('SELECT dossierid FROM dossiers', [])
    # return jsonify(ids)
    print(ids[1].get('DossierId'))

    results = []
    for id in ids:
        results.append(get_dossier(id.get('DossierId')))
    return jsonify(results)
```

The JS:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', `http://127.0.0.1:5000/dossiers/all`, true)
request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    data.forEach((dossier) => {
      const card = document.createElement('button')
      card.setAttribute('class', 'card')

      const kruisje = document.createElement('button')
      kruisje.setAttribute('class', 'kruisje')

      const h1 = document.createElement('h1')
      h1.textContent = dossier.ziekte

      const p = document.createElement('p')
      dossier.description = dossier.description.substring(0, 300)
      p.textContent = `${dossier.behandeling}...`

      const id = dossier.dossierId

      container.appendChild(card)
      card.appendChild(kruisje)
      card.appendChild(h1)
      card.appendChild(p)

      card.addEventListener("click", function() {
        window.location = `dossier.html?id=${dossier.id}`
      })
    })
  } else {
    const errorMessage = document.createElement('p')
    errorMessage.textContent = `Het werkt niet...`
    app.appendChild(errorMessage)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can a few things, and it's hard to say what exactly from your description.

1. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Depending on whether you open one as `localhost` and request the other as `127.0.0.1`, you can need to set [`XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials).
2. Depending on how `login_required` decorator works, you may have HTML login page when you're not authenticated.
3. If you're running `Flask < 0.11`, then [`jsonify`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify) won't if you're passing it a `list`.

   > *Changed in version 0.11:* Added support for serializing top-level arrays. This introduces a security risk in ancient browsers. See [JSON Security](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/security/#security-json).

   Basically the vulnerability of `Array.prototype` override while fetching JSON resource as Javascript only exists in ancient browsers and root lists are fine to use. A couple of examples with [`pex`](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex). I have this in `app.py`.

   ```
   from flask import Flask, jsonify

   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/dossiers', methods=['GET'])
   def dossiers():
       return jsonify([{'foo': 'bar'}])

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run()
   ```

   - `pex "flask < 0.11" -- app.py`

     ```sh
     $ curl -v localhost:5000/dossiers
     *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
     * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
     > GET /dossiers HTTP/1.1
     > Host: localhost:5000
     > User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
     > Accept: */*
     > 
     * HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
     < HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
     < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
     < Content-Length: 290
     < Server: Werkzeug/2.0.1 Python/3.7.10
     < Date: Mon, 24 May 2021 13:05:12 GMT
     ...
     ```
   - `pex "flask >= 0.11" -- app.py`

     ```sh
     $ curl -v localhost:5000/dossiers
     *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
     * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
     > GET /dossiers HTTP/1.1
     > Host: localhost:5000
     > User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
     > Accept: */*
     > 
     * HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
     < HTTP/1.0 200 OK
     < Content-Type: application/json
     < Content-Length: 16
     < Server: Werkzeug/2.0.1 Python/3.7.10
     < Date: Mon, 24 May 2021 13:07:18 GMT
     < 
     [{"foo":"bar"}]
     * Closing connection 0
     ```